# How to retrieve the visible texture from a png image in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am making a question answer game in which the answer images are made as sprites from png images.

The answer image is like this:

[image]

I am making rect on the image like this:

```
Rect rect = Rect(answerSprites.at(i)->getBoundingBox().origin.x,
                    answerSprites.at(i)->getBoundingBox().origin.y,
                    answerSprites.at(i)->getBoundingBox().size.width,
                    answerSprites.at(i)->getBoundingBox().size.height);
```

Then i am detecting touch on the rect as :

```
void HelloWorld::onTouchesBegan(const std::vector<Touch*>& touches,
        Event *unused_event) {
    auto target = static_cast<Sprite*>(unused_event->getCurrentTarget());
    auto touchPointBegan = (Touch*) touches.front();
    Vec2 locationBegan = touchPointEnded->getLocation();
    Point locationInNode = target->convertToNodeSpace(locationEnded);
    Size s = target->getContentSize();
        if (rect.containsPoint(locationInNode)) {
            log(“Correct Touch”);
        }
}
```

The code is working fine but the problem is that it is detecting the touch on the full png, but i want to detect the touch on the flower only.
The flower can be at any position on the png.

How can i make the rect only on the flower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the transparency of the touch location with this code:

```
// Answer sprite
m_sprite = Sprite::create("answer-1.png");
m_sprite->setPosition( Vec2(winSize.width*.5, winSize.height*.5)  );
addChild(m_sprite);

bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(const cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    _originPoint = touch->getLocation();
    _destinationPoint = _originPoint;

    Vec2 locationInNode = m_sprite->convertToNodeSpace(touch->getLocation());

    Rect rect = Rect(m_sprite->getBoundingBox().origin.x,
                     m_sprite->getBoundingBox().origin.y,
                     m_sprite->getContentSize().width,
                     m_sprite->getContentSize().height);


    if (rect.containsPoint(touch->getLocation() )) {

        if (tapsOnNonTransparent(locationInNode, "answer-1.png" )) {
            log("Correct Touch");
        }

    }

    return true;
}

const bool HelloWorld::tapsOnNonTransparent( const cocos2d::Point& tap, const std::string &spritePath )
{
    auto imgPtr = std::make_unique<cocos2d::Image>();
    imgPtr->initWithImageFile( spritePath );

    const int width = imgPtr ->getWidth();
    const int height = imgPtr ->getHeight();

    unsigned x = unsigned( tap.x ) % width;
    /// Don't forget to invert y coordinate.
    unsigned y = unsigned( height - tap.y ) % height;
    unsigned index = x + y * width;
    unsigned dataLen = imgPtr ->getDataLen();
    CCAssert( index < dataLen, "index is bigger than image size." );
    unsigned char* pixel = imgPtr->getData() + (4 * index);
    return !isZeroPixel( pixel );
}

const bool HelloWorld::isZeroPixel( const unsigned char* pixel )
{
    return 0 == pixel[0] && 0 == pixel[1] && 0 == pixel[2] && 0 == pixel[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle you create covers the entire image. It would be a better approach to separate the flower and the frame.

Create a Sprite for the frame image and create a Button for the flower image. Then add the button as a child to frame.

```
auto spriteFrame = Sprite::create("frame.png");
spriteFrame->setPosition(Vec2(300,300));
addChild(spriteFrame);

auto btn = ui::Button::create("flower.png");
btn->setZoomScale(0);
// Place in the middle of the frame sprite
btn->setPosition(Vec2(spriteFrame->getContentSize().width*.5, spriteFrame->getContentSize().height*.5));
btn->addClickEventListener([=](Ref* sender){
    log("Correct Touch");
});
spriteFrame->addChild(btn);
```

Comment: Actually the designer wants to change the position in every image.  I have around 1000 images and i don't know where the flower will be on the png..... so i need a way to extract tge texture from png..

Comment: baris, make the button position & size taken from xml/json/etc, so they can position the active image part.

Comment: or you can, get RGB from the texture and check whether the touched area is transparent or some other color.

Comment: As @sanchitgulati said, you may create tool for your artist to prepare answer nodes by positioning the button inside the frame. Or you may check the transparency of the touched location. Look at my new answer for checking the transparency of the image